# Working Out A Router IP Address

Tags: routing, router, ipv4, ip-address

in my exam i got completely derailed when i was asked to find the router ip address. i was given the following information about the network:

VLANS:

Managment Address: `198.72.210.64/26`

Student Address:`142.60.32.1/21`

Loopback:`53.20.5.32/27`

---

Network layout:

not sure if this is needed, the network had 1 router 2 switches and 1 pc

---

given this information how do i find the routers ip address?

Thanks for taking the time to read this, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a router any valid host address on the network. The router is the host on the network that knows how to forward traffic to other networks.

Some people always use the first valid host address, and some people always use the last valid host address. You can use any valid host address. It doesn't matter, but it really helps to be consistent.

If the network uses DHCP, then it needs to be the gateway passed out by the DHCP server, or you need to make sure the DHCP server is passing out the router address for the network.

Comment: sorry so i have another question, how do you determine what is the first valid address?

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).